# Getting absolute position of an element in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I am trying to create an overlay effect on mouseover of all elements. I wrote this js code, it works for most of the scenarios and fails under some conditions.

**JS Code**

```
$(function() {
    var overlay = $("<div id='overlay'></div>").css({position:"absolute","display":"none","background":"red"});
        $("body").append(overlay);
        $("body").on("mouseover", function(e) {
            var t = e.target;
            var offset = $(t).offset();
            var top = offset.top;
            var left = offset.left;
            var scrollx = $(window).scrollTop();
            var scrolly = $(window).scrollLeft();
            top -= scrolly;
            left -= scrollx;
    console.log(overlay);              overlay.css({"top":top,"left":left,"width":"50px","height":"2px"});
            overlay.show();
        });

});
```

**JS Fiddle**

https://fiddle.jshell.net/go2j4fk7/12/show/light/

**Failure Conditions**

1. Trying to mouseover element inside an iframe. I use $("iframe").contents().mouseover() to bind event.
2. If parent element has scroll
3. If element is in fixed position.

How to create an overlay for any element?

Comment: [Works better](http://fiddle.jshell.net/magh180o/)  without scrolling position detection.

Comment: @Teemu it won't work for most of the scenarios.